# Why isn't the char changing the way I Intend it too?

Tags: c#, char, calculator

I am new here so please excuse me for the poor formatting,
I wrote a simple calculator in c# but it seems my multiplication and division are not working correctly.
when running the code it works fine until I try to output the answer and then it outputs "Error, Unknown operator" which is what I told it to output when it doesn't identify the operator stored in the operation variable.
 here is the code (sorry for dumping so much code, I am not sure what is relevant and what is not):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) // method called "main", when the program starts, this runs
        {
        start:
            // variable declarations
            double Num1;
            double Num2;
            int operationId;
            string operationName = "1";
            string operationName2 = "1";
            Char operation;
            double answer;

            // choosing an operator
            Console.WriteLine("select an operation from the list and type it's associated number:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - sum \n" + "2 - subtraction \n" + "3 - division\n" + "4 - multipication \n");
            operationId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // checking which operation has been chosen
            if (operationId == 1)
            {
                operationName = "added to";
                operationName2 = "added";
                operation = '+';
            } else if (operationId == 2)
            {
                operationName = "subtracted from";
                operationName2 = "subtracted";
                operation = '-';
            } else if (operationId == 3) 
            {
                operationName = "divided";
                operationName2 = "divided by";
                operation = '/';
            } else if (operationId == 4)
            {
                operationName = "multiplied";
                operationName2 = "multiplied by";
                operation = '*';
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid option");
                goto start;
            }

            // receving user input
            Console.WriteLine("Insert a number to be " + operationName + ":");
            Num1 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert a number to be " + operationName2);
            Num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            //calculating answer
            if (operation == '+')
            {
                answer = Num1 + Num2;
            }
            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                answer = Num1 - Num2;
            }
            else if (operationId == '/')
            {
                answer = Num1 / Num2;
            }
            else if (operationId == '*')
            {
                answer = Num1 + Num2;
            } else
            {
                answer = 0000;
                Console.WriteLine("Error, Unknown operator \n");
                goto start;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The result is:");
            Console.WriteLine(answer);

            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();
            goto start;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great time to become familiar with the debugger. You could've found your issue in less time that it took to post this question (not trying to be snarky, it's just true).

Comment: Why not just `answer = 0;` instead of `answer = 0000;`? It's a `double` so the extra 0's do nothing.

Comment: Also, just some friendly advice: `goto` is **really** frowned upon in C#. It's a huge code smell and 99.99% of the time it means you need to refactor your code.

Comment: Bouncing off @BrootsWaymb's comment, a `while` loop would be the standard practice for something like this. I don't think I've ever seen a legitimate use for `goto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first 2 `if`s check `operation`, the second 2 check `operationId`. Change the multiply and divide ones to also check `operation`.

```
//...
else if (operation == '/')
{
    answer = Num1 / Num2;
}
else if (operation == '*')
{
    answer = Num1 * Num2; //<-- Change to this from Num1 + Num2
}
//...
```

And by the way, your multiply block is adding the numbers, not multiplying. I've fixed that in my block above.

Comment: thanks, feeling a bit stupid for not spotting such an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with - 2 conditions are checking operation and 2 conditions are checking operationId. Perhaps you may want to change all the checks to be either with operation or with operationId.

```
if (operation == '+')
        {
            answer = Num1 + Num2;
        }
        else if (operation == '-')
        {
            answer = Num1 - Num2;
        }
        else if (operationId == '/')
        {
            answer = Num1 / Num2;
        }
        else if (operationId == '*')
        {
            answer = Num1 + Num2;
        } else
        {
            answer = 0000;
            Console.WriteLine("Error, Unknown operator \n");
            goto start;
        }
```